# Hibernate : An association from the table application_category refers to an unmapped class: allin.beans1.Application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use :

- netbeans 8.x
- Mysql database
- analyseSI for design database
- Hibernate as ORM.

I try to associate 2 tables : User and Application.

I use an association table named : User_Application.

Here my User.hmb.xml

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="allin.beans1.User" table="user" catalog="allin" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="user_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="username" type="string">
            <column name="username" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="first_name" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="last_name" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="age" type="java.lang.Short">
            <column name="age" />
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="phone" />
        </property>
        <property name="userCreation" type="timestamp">
            <column name="user_creation" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="userLastReq" type="string">
            <column name="user_last_req" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <property name="userError" type="string">
            <column name="user_error" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <set name="applications" table="user_application" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="allin.beans1.Application">
                <column name="application_id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here my Application.hmb.xml :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="allin.beans1.Application" table="application" catalog="allin" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="applicationId" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="application_id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="applicationName" type="string">
            <column name="application_name" length="254" />
        </property>
        <property name="applicationDescription" type="string">
            <column name="application_description" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <property name="applicationCreation" type="timestamp">
            <column name="application_creation" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="applicationUpdate" type="timestamp">
            <column name="application_update" length="19" />
        </property>
        <property name="applicationLastReq" type="string">
            <column name="application_last_req" length="65535" />
        </property>
        <set name="users" table="user_application" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="application_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="allin.beans1.User">
                <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
        <set name="categories" table="application_category" inverse="false" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="application_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="allin.beans1.Category">
                <column name="category_id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here my hibernate conf :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/allin?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <mapping resource="allin/beans1/Category.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="allin/beans1/Application.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="allin/beans1/User.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have this error when runing a simple command like "From User" :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table user_application refers to an unmapped class: allin.beans1.Application
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1805)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1739)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configueration.java:1424)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
```

The line where i think the bug is (in file User.hmb.xml) :

```
 <many-to-many entity-name="allin.beans1.Application">
            <column name="category_id" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-many>
```

It's like it didn't find the file Application.hbm.xml in User.hmb.xml ... I forget a flag or something ?

thanks for you help guys !

EDIT :

Database script :

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User ; CREATE TABLE User (user_id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, username VARCHAR(254), password VARCHAR(254), email VARCHAR(254), first_name VARCHAR(254), last_name VARCHAR(254), age SMALLINT, phone INT, user_creation DATETIME, user_last_req TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (user_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Application ; CREATE TABLE Application (application_id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, application_name VARCHAR(254), application_description TEXT, application_creation DATETIME, application_update DATETIME, application_last_req TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (application_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Category ; CREATE TABLE Category (category_id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, category_name VARCHAR(254), category_description TEXT, category_last_req TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (category_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User_Application ; CREATE TABLE User_Application (user_id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, application_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (user_id,  application_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Application_Category ; CREATE TABLE Application_Category (application_id INT  AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, category_id INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (application_id,  category_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB;  ALTER TABLE User_Application ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_Application_user_id FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES User (user_id); ALTER TABLE User_Application ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_Application_application_id FOREIGN KEY (application_id) REFERENCES Application (application_id); ALTER TABLE Application_Category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Application_Category_application_id FOREIGN KEY (application_id) REFERENCES Application (application_id); ALTER TABLE Application_Category ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Application_Category_category_id FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES Category (category_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**May be** application_id present in user table but you mentioned entity-name as application change it to user

```
 <set name="applications" table="user_application" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="user_id" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <many-to-many entity-name="**allin.beans1.User**">
                <column name="application_id" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-many>
        </set>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I add the data base script on my post.

application_id is not present in user table.

If i change it to user i would not have my association between User and Application ... I need to set it at Applicaiton